# How can I create a v1.0 zip archive?

Tags: zip

How can I make a v1.0 zip archive, so that when ran against `file` returns

```
Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

When I create a zip file with the `zip` command line utility or Xarchiver, `file` returns

```
Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the v2.0 zip utility was the first to support compression. Zip archives that require 'at least v1.0 to extract' can be created by passing `-0` (no compression) to the `zip` utility.

Comment: Version 1 did support compression. Version 2 introduced the “deflate” algorithm, and that’s what results in archives which can’t be extracted with version 1. Info-Zip’s `zip` *only* supports deflation in version 2, none of the other ZIP compression algorithms, so your solution is indeed the only way to produce v1-compatible archives using that tool, but the explanation is incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

You can create version 1 ZIP archives using Info-Zip’s `zip` 1.1, which is [still available](ftp://ftp.info-zip.org/pub/infozip/src/) (download `zip11.zip`). You’ll need to build it from source (`make sysv` on a Linux system); then you’ll be able to use the newly-built `zip` to create old-format archives:

```
$ ./zip -9 test.zip zip.c
adding zip.c (imploded 70%)
$ file test.zip
test.zip: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
$ unzip -v test.zip
Archive:  test.zip
 Length   Method    Size  Cmpr    Date    Time   CRC-32   Name
--------  ------  ------- ---- ---------- ----- --------  ----
   25825  Implode    7749  70% 10-21-1991 13:33 e1f47bfc  zip.c
--------          -------  ---                            -------
   25825             7749  70%                            1 file
```

This uses the “implode” or “shrink” algorithms for compression (it uses whichever is better with any given file), rather than the “deflate” algorithm used in version 2 of the format.